# I want to show a specific user's current pfp as command result

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{ID.name}'s current avatar is", description="Test", color=discord.Color.magenta())
    embed.set_image(url=user.ID.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

however, using their ID's didnt seem to work...
What should I do instead of using thier ID's directly?

Comment: From where exactly are you taking the `ID` variable?

Comment: oh they gave their ID's theirselves

Comment: where? I don't see you passing the ID in the command

Comment: well its 291094866778259457

Comment: I don't care what's the ID, I'm voting to close this question as it needs debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ID` or the user you want pfp of

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx. m: discord.Member):
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{m.name}'s current avatar is", description="Test", color=discord.Color.magenta())
    embed.set_image(url=m.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```